# Sorting cv::Mat in OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there an equivalent function in OpenCV similar to `[srtd,srtdinds] = sort(dst,'ascend');` in Matlab? I have tried `cv::sortIdx(source, dst, cv::SORT_ASCENDING);` but it doesn't work. My source `Mat` contains a single column.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation of [`cv::sortIdx()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sortidx#void%20sortIdx%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags%29):

> Instead of reordering the elements themselves, it stores the indices of sorted elements in the output array.

This means that you will need to call `cv::sort()` to sort the elements themselves after calling `cv::sortIdx()` to replicate the behavior of Matlab's `sort()` function:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32F), dst;
cv::sortIdx(source, dst, CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW + CV_SORT_ASCENDING);
cv::sort(source, source, CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW + CV_SORT_ASCENDING);
```

Now `dst` contains the permuted indices, and `source` contains the sorted data itself.

Comment: Why do you sort two times? This is inefficient. You can basically use sortIdx once and just re-index the elements.