# sort whole Mat image and store indices in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

This question is not the duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831753/sorting-cvmat-in-opencv)

I want to sort the whole `Mat image` and store the indices similar to the `MatLab's [B , Ix] = sort(A);`

But in openCV, the [**sort()**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sort) and [sortIdx()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sortidx) only works for `EACH_ROW` or `EACH_COLUMN`.

**Problem:** So, how can i sort the whole `Mat` and store the `Indices` also in openCV?

**PS:**  I want to get the following:

INPUT =

2 0

4 1

dst_index =

1 1

2 2

dst_sorted =

0 1

2 4

Answer (score 2):

There are a solution but it works only if the image is continuous in memory. This is usually the case unless your image is only a ROI of bigger image. You can check that by using function  [isContinuous](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous). The trick is to create Mat that uses the same memory buffer as your original image but instead of treating it as N rows and M columns, it treat it as 1 row and M*N columns. This can be done by [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) function.

```
Mat sameMemoryNewShape = image.reshape(1, 1);
```

Now you can use sort() or sortIdx() on sameMemoryNewShape.

Comment: @Micheal: Thanks, the sorting is working and i am able to get ` 0 1 2 4` for the above input but for index, i am getting `1 0 0 0`...how?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of 'Michael Burdinov' the following should work.

```
Mat A = (Mat_<uchar>(3, 4) << 0, 5, 2, 5, 2, 4, 9, 12, 3, 12, 11, 1); // example matrix
Mat B; //storing the 1D index result
Mat C = A.reshape(1, 1); //as mentioned by Michael Burdinov
sortIdx(C, B, SORT_EVERY_ROW + SORT_ASCENDING);
for (int i = 0; i < B.cols; i++) //from index 0 to index rows * cols of the original image
{
    int val =  B.at<int>(0, i); //access B, which is in format CV_32SC1
    int y = val / A.cols; //convert 1D index into 2D index
    int x = val % A.cols;
    std::cout << "idx " << val << " at (x/y) " << x << "/" << y
              << " is " << (int) A.at<uchar>(y, x) << endl;
}
```

Note that the result `B` is in CV_32SC1 (32bit integer). Not considering that may lead to "strange" behaviour and could result in `1 0 0 0`.