# plotting histograms of each channel of a BGR image.

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing a computer vision based project in open cv.I want to plot the histograms each channel of a BGR image in the same window.I did it by splitting the image in 3 channels and then applying `calcHist` to each. Is there any way to do it by using the function only once and changing the parameters .Also I did not properly understand the `const int* channels` parameter in `calcHist` function.

Comment: sometimes separating RGB is not a good idea in DIP/CV in such case take a look at [HSV histogram showed as 3D graph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29286584/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [offical tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html#gsc.tab=0) about plotting histogram of the image. [here is the link for calcHist_Demo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Histograms_Matching/calcHist_Demo.cpp)