# How to display Histogram in RGB and HSV of video frame in one window using OpenCV (C++)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, canvas, histogram

I am trying to display image frame from the video and its histograms in one window using canvas. Here is the piece of my code. It displays only the image but not the histogram, I am saving the calculated histogram in `cv::Mat` histogram. Separately the histogram in another window is displayed without problem. **makeCanvas** is from [here](http://qubanshi.cc/questions/604373/show-multiple-2-3-4-images-in-the-same-window-in-opencv)

```
vector<Mat> vecMat1;
vecMat1.push_back(frame);
vecMat1.push_back(histogram);
cv::namedWindow("canvas");
cv::imshow("canvas", makeCanvas(vecMat1, 600, 2));`
```

Is it possible to do? Any references, any information is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is `histogram` an image of the histogram or the histogram as a simple 1d-array? In other words, does `cv::imshow("histogram", histogram) look as expected?

Comment: I would use this: [HSV histogram showed as 3D graph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29286584/2521214)

Comment: @chtz `histogram` is as an image, it can be displayed in different window, but not in canvas together with image.