# Printing Histogram with C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, histogram

I am trying to print a histogram using for loops, but, for some reason my second loop which is supposed to run based on if conditions, is not working, and I end up having only 1 `"#"` for each counter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

char hash = '#';                                
double list[10];                                
int size = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);      

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                 
  list[i] = ((rand() % 10000) / 10000.0);       

  for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {              
    if
    (      
        (list[i] >= 0 && list[i] <= .1) ||
        (list[i] >= .1 && list[i] <= .2) || 
        (list[i] >= .2 && list[i] < .3) ||
        (list[i] >= .3 && list[i] < .4) ||
        (list[i] >= .4 && list[i] < .5) ||
        (list[i] >= .5 && list[i] < .6) ||
        (list[i] >= .6 && list[i] < .7) ||
        (list[i] >= .7 && list[i] < .8) ||
        (list[i] >= .8 && list[i] < .9) ||
        (list[i] >= .9 && list[i] < 1.0)
    ) 
      {
      list[i] += 1;             
    }
  }
}

cout << "HISTOGRAM OF 10 COUNTERS " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  cout << "[" << i << "] \t" << list[i] << "\t" << string(list[i], hash) << endl;
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The for loop tests the same value 10000 times.You probably want to use `j` somewhere in it. That said, stop writing code. Think this out with pen-on-paper and then return to code with a plan.

Comment: Your multiline `if` condition is the same as testing for `list[i]` being between 0 and 1, and that is obviously not what you intended. Relook at your logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, but since this looks like homework that you should do on your own, I will just explain the observed behaviour:

In each iteration of the outer for loop `list[i]` is initially set to a value between 0 and 1. Your `if` condition can be shortened to `list[i] >= 0. && list[i] < 1.`. It will always match on the first iteration of the loop. But then you add `1` to that value. As a result, it won't match any of the subsequent evaluations of that condition, because then `list[i]` is `1 + original value of list[i]`, which is not between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. **You are using `list[]` for random numbers and for histogram**

   **That is wrong!** The random values should be stored in temp variable and generated in main loop (`j<10000`) instead.
2. **the for loops should not be nested**

   The first one (`i<10`) should just clear your histogram to zero. The second should generate your random value, compute histogramn bin index from it and increment the bin count by one.
3. **The big `if` condition**

   is not complete and it should be (`size=10`) individual or `if/else` conditions that compute `i` index. Also it should use the temp random value instead of histogram value:

   ```
   random_value=((rand()%10000)/10000.0);
   i=-1;if (random_value<0.0);
   else if (random_value<0.1) i=0;
   else if (random_value<0.2) i=1;
   else if (random_value<0.3) i=2;
   ...
   else if (random_value<1.0) i=9;
   if (i>=0) list[i]++;
   ```

   However your random value is in range `<0.0,1.0)` so ifs can be removed completely by:

   ```
   random_value=((rand()%10000)/10000.0);
   i=floor(random_value*double(size));
   list[i]++;
   ```

For more info see

- [opencv drawing a 2d histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29286584/2521214)

You can find there C++ histogram example ..